# Why can const be used to set a value in a for..of loop?

Tags: javascript, constants

The below code, `const` is something that cannot be changed, so why can I use `const x` when every iteration the x changes?

```
for (const x of fruits.keys()) {    
   console.log(x);
   text += x + "<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: `const` is scoped to the block, so what that means is that `x` cannot change *in the body of the `for` loop*. Each iteration of the loop everything gets reset, but you can't do `for (const x of someArray) { x = 5; }`

Comment: @JaredSmith I wouldn't even use the phrase "reset", which sounds like there is only one `x`. Rather, it gets *(re)created* for each iteration.